# How do I tell if a folder contains a file with a specific extension?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a folder, how do I tell if it contains any files of a specified extension? I don't need file names or how many files contain that extension; I just need to determine if a file with the extension is present.

Comment: "too broad"... Can someone explain what I need to be more specific about? Five downvotes and not a single comment explaining how to improve whatever you see as reason to downvote. "There are either too many possible answers..." How? I'm quite specific about what I need. "good answers would be too long for this format..." Nope, two one liners within minutes of asking the question. "Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." Doesn't seem necessary since people have given acceptable answers.

Comment: I found this question to be specific and answerable, as evidenced by two answers which didn't require any guesswork or requests for clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `any` function to test if any of the file string end with the desired extension string.

```
any(i.endswith(extension) for i in os.listdir(directory))
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple one-liner will do it:

```
any(ext == os.path.splitext(name)[1] for name in os.listdir(path))
```

Assuming `path` is the dir path, and `ext` is the extension string.

Comment: This is the only correct way (so far). +1

Comment: This uses the equivalent of `if name == True: return True`. Instead of `True for name in iterable if condition`, you can just do `condition for name in iterable`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Fair point. Edited to simplify. I forgot that `any` short circuits as it is lazily evaluated for an input generator.